# Flutter: How to change title: TextStyle when check box is selected?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make the `TextStyle` of the `title:` of `CheckboxList` change to strikethrough when the checkbox is selected but I can't work out how to do it.

I tried creating two strings and use them in `setState`:

```
String labelText = 'inital text of the label';  // so "title: Text(labelText),"
String strikeLabelText = Text(labelText,
     style: TextStyle(TextDecoration.lineThrough)); // so in setState "_value = strikeLabelText"
```

My last effort was putting an `if statement` in the `setState` part as below. This obviously didn't work but I added it to show what I am trying to achieve:

```
class CheckBoxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckBoxWidget> createState() => _CheckBoxWidgetState();
}

class _CheckBoxWidgetState extends State<CheckBoxWidget> {
  bool _value = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('labelText'),
        autofocus: false,
        value: _value,
        secondary: const Icon(Icons.double_arrow),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value!;
            if (_value == true) {
              title.Text(
                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
              );
            }
          });
        });
  }
}
```

I've seen some attempts at a solution but none work for me and they seem overly complicated for what seems a simple task. There was one that used `Theme` to change the `TextStyle` but I couldn't make that work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly change the text decoration based on the condition with ternary operator like this:

```
title: Text(
                'labelText',
                style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: _value ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
              ),
```

and `setState`should only be used to update that value.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd never heard of that operator before.